# How to get rid of numbers next to code in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwozZ.png)

How to I get rid of these numbers next to each code line in my notebook? I cannot think of what shortcut I used by accident to get them there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`Esc + l` turns off line numbers in Jupyter

Comment: Or from the 'File' menubar that will be above your notebook, choose `View` > `Toggle Line Numbers`.